# How to make a hybrid ARIMA and SVMs model in R

Tags: r, svm

I want to combine 2 awesome models for data prediction / forecast - an ARIMA and an SVMs model, and thus I want to reduce standard error for the hybrid model. Currently, here's a graph showing them in action:

[image: current ARIMA + SVM model]

I don't exactly know how to combine both models together. My way is to fit the result of the ARIMA prediction to an SVM classifier. However, my method produces a higher error in all 4 categories (MAE, MAPE, MSE and RMSE):

[image: errors]

row 1 - ARIMA fit

row 2 - SVMs fit

row 3 - ARIMA + SVMs combination (my method)

This is my source code:

```
# Time series data
data_ts <- ts(daily_data[, c('cnt')])

# ARIMA model
arima_seasonal <-
    Arima(
    data_ts,
    order = c(2, 1, 2),
    seasonal = c(1, 0, 1),
    include.drift = TRUE
    )
arima_seasonal_pred <- fitted(arima_seasonal)

# SVM model
svm_tune <- tune.svm(
    data_ts ~ daily_data$date,
     data = daily_data,
     gamma = 2 ^ (-1:1),
     cost = 2 ^ (2:8),
     epsilon = seq(0, 1, 0.1),
     kernel = "radial"
 )
 # - best parameters:
 # gamma cost epsilon
 # 2     256  0.4
 svm_model <- svm_tune$best.model

svm_pred <- fitted(svm_model)

# ARIMA + SVM
arima_svm_tune <- tune.svm(
    arima_seasonal_pred ~ daily_data$date,
     data = daily_data,
     gamma = 2 ^ (-1:1),
     cost = 2 ^ (2:8),
     epsilon = seq(0, 1, 0.1),
     kernel = "radial"
 )
 arima_svm <- arima_svm_tune$best.model
arima_svm_pred <- fitted(arima_svm)

label1 <- "Actual data"
label2 <- "ARIMA model"
label3 <- "SVMs"
label4 <- "Hybrid model"

# Plot them
graph <- ggplot(daily_data) +
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = cnt, colour = label1), size = .4) +
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = arima_seasonal_pred, colour = label2)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = date, y = arima_seasonal_pred, colour = label2), size = 0.5) +
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = svm_pred, colour = label3), size = .4) +
    geom_point(aes(x = date, y = svm_pred, colour = label3), size = 0.5) +
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = arima_svm_pred, colour = label4), size = .4) +
    geom_point(aes(x = date, y = arima_svm_pred, colour = label4), size = 0.5) +
    scale_x_date("Date") +
    ylab("Bicycle Sales")
graph$labels$colour <- "Legend"

ggsave(
    filename = "arima_svm_pred_1.png",
    plot = graph,
    width = 10,
    height = 6
)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.